# Accessing Job ID during gridengine submission

Tags: gridengine

I am using a bash script to submit jobs to gridengine.

Is there a way for the script to know the job ID assigned to it by the scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

The job number is available as the `$JOB_ID` environment variable.